# SailsJS user access levels and roles

Tags: sails.js, passport.js

I am using what I have learnt [here](https://ericswann.wordpress.com/2015/04/24/nozus-js-1-intro-to-sails-with-passport-and-jwt-json-web-token-auth/comment-page-1/) to build a user authentication system. Essentially it is using passport local auth.

How would I add users access levels and roles to SailsJS? For example I would like access levels (canWriteAll, canWriteOwn, canRead) with user roles that these are assigned to (admin, contributor, user...etc..).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sails has built-in policy based access control system. [Check out documentation](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/policies) first.

The simple form if it is:

- create required access level attribute in your User model equal to most basic access level by default. This can be number (like 1 - administrator and 100 - unauthenticated user, and other roles between them) or string (like `administrator`, `moderator`, `guest`) or anything.
- create middlewares in `policies` folder (check documentation for examples).
- in [`policies`](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/anatomy/my-app/config/policies-js) configuration file add policy for each controller and their methods.

Like:

```
UserController: {
  '*': false,                    // disallow for each method not listed here
  find: ['guest'],               // check guest.js middleware for permission
  destroy: ['administrator']     // check administrator.js middleware for permission
}
```

Comment: Thanks Glen I will give this a try and acceptif I have no issues. Your answer has helped clear the process up for me.

Comment: Ok, I have added an access level attribute to my User model. and added the required controls to policies.js. I have also added two files to my policies folder 'isAdmin.js' and 'isUser.js' but I am having trouble accessing the model attributes inside my middleware, How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I may be a little late to post answer here, But there is one other way is available for access control in sails.

Below link for documentation.

[access-control-and-permissions](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/policies/access-control-and-permissions)

Policies in Sails are designed for controlling binary ("yes or no") access to particular actions. They work great for checking whether a user is logged in or for other simple "yes or no" checks, like whether the logged in user is a "super admin".

But for Dynamic permissions,

For more complex permission schemes, like those in which a requesting user agent's access rights depend on both who they are and what they're trying to do, you'll want to involve the database. While you can use policies to accomplish this, it's usually more straightforward and maintainable to use a helper.

One can find example here,
[Using helper for access control and permission](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/policies/access-control-and-permissions#?dynamic-permissions)