# What is the best way to create user defined roles and apply ACL dynamically on controllers in Sail.js?

Tags: sails.js

What is the best way to create user defined roles and apply ACL dynamically on controllers in Sail.js ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34966237/sailsjs-user-access-levels-and-roles) explaining the built-in policy based access control system to manage user roles in Sails for controllers.

Official docs: [policies.js](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/policies) and [access control and permissions](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/policies/access-control-and-permissions).